# How do I use a particle system and geometry nodes at the same time?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, geometry-nodes

I have a plane with wheat on it using a particle system. I used a geometry node setup to scatter trees around but when I do so, the particle system stops working and the wheat disappears.

Top Down View - Weight Paint Mode:
Wheat (labelled 1.)
[image]

Weight painted some trees in and Wheat disappears
[image]

Geometry Node Setup for the Trees
[image]

[image]

Comment: i cannot reproduce that [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngsCM.png so pls provide blend file so we can check it out. thx.

Comment: @chris I've ddded it. Also, may I know if you are using a geometry setup to spread points and a particle system at the same time? If yes, may I know how??

Comment: yes, but i didn't use vertex groups

Comment: so, the problem has to be something to do with the vertex groups I used then. have you tried it with vertex groups?

Comment: yes, and i saw the same result as you. I tried a few other things but i didn't get it working :(

Comment: i think i have understood the problem (but i might be wrong) - but i didn't get a solution. You define a vertex group - but GN of course changes the data and i think it "looses" the information. So you have to change GN in that way, that it keeps that information.

Comment: I see. that makes sense. but I'm not sure how to keep the information. I'll keep searching

Comment: ok, got it: add a realize instances after the instance on points and move the particles in the modifier before the GN. Then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a realize instances after the instance on points and move the particles in the modifier before the GN.

result:

[image]

Comment: You absolute legend. Thank you Chris!!! It WOrkeD

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: I unaccepted your answer. It works but there's a slight problem. That node causes some [problems](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299407/realize-instance-node-causing-issues-with-weight-paint-view) with the weight paint view. just try it yourself.

Comment: your decision. But that wasn't your question. Of course you can change your question afterwards - but that's not how this site works. And i will think in the future whether i will help you again...

Comment: Didn't really change my question. Just wanted other people who possibly see this not to think that it's the 100% working answer. That's why I created a new question