# "Realize Instance" node causing Weight Paint View effect are colors to become invisible

Tags: geometry-nodes, particles, weight-paint-mode

I've created a geometry node setup to scatter some trees while using a vertex group for the density and used a *Realize Instances* node so that it would work together with hair particle systems (for grass as an example).

However, this has caused the weight paint view to stop working properly. It turns blue as usual but none of the weight colors shows making me have to connect and reconnect the node back and forth to weight paint.

Why is this happening? Specifically with the "realize instance" node which is clearly what caused this.

Realize Instance Node Connected In The Chain - Weight Paint View

[image: 1]

Realize Instance Node Disconnect, Particle System stops working, Weight Paint Works - Weight Paint View

[image: 1]

This question is related to one of my [previous questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299233/how-do-i-use-a-particle-system-and-geometry-nodes-at-the-same-time) that I just got a working answer to. But now this happens.